# Function Cannot Be Called: Python

Tags: python, function

I'm self learning python and I have to create three functions: first_word, second_word and last_word. These functions have to take a sentence and then return either the first, the second or the last word. For example with the sentence "once upon a time there was a programmer" it would return once, upon, programmer. My code does return the words correctly but the second one cannot be called.

```
def first_word(sentence):
    m = sentence.find(" ")
    return(sentence[0:m])

def second_word(sentence):
    l = sentence.find(" ")
    k = l + 1
    j = l + 1
    while sentence[j] != " ":
        j += 1
    return(sentence[k:j]) 

def last_word(sentence):
    g = -1
    while sentence[g] != " ":
        g -= 1
    return(sentence[g + 1 : len(sentence)])
```

With that code I am receiving this error message:
[image]

PS: I am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: It sounds like it's simply returning the wrong result, or indexing out of bounds.  Just try calling it yourself with the example it gave you"  `second_word("first second")`.  What does it do?  You may be indexing out of bounds.  Try it.

Comment: Also, you should do some error checking.  Your code seems to assume that all inputs are what you expect.  They aren't.  For instance, `find` may return `-1` if there's no space.  Make sure you're handling that properly.  And in the example given, there's a single space, which you skip past.  You then look for a second space.  There isn't one.  Bug.  The second word may or may not exist, but if it does, then it's terminated by either (1) a space or (2) the end of the string.  You aren't handling case 2.  Work through some examples.  Fix your mistakes.

Comment: A suggestion:  There is a built-in string function `split` which breaks a string into 'words' by splitting (by default) on space; you can use this to put the words into a List then just pick the one you want so s[0], s[1], s[-1] . This removes the need for looping. Then you could simply have one function and pass to it the part you want which avoids repetition.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using *str.find()* this is better implemented with *str.split()*

Always check to see if your function can deal with the values passed to it.

Here is a more robust approach:

```
def first_word(sentence: str) -> str | None:
    if sentence:
        return sentence.split()[0]

def second_word(sentence: str) -> str | None:
    if sentence:
        if len(words := sentence.split()) > 1:
            return words[1]

def last_word(sentence: str) -> str | None:
    if sentence:
        return sentence.split()[-1]
```